# Google web designer trouble

Tags: google-web-designer

Accomplished half part of the project in Google web designer and got a trouble with text formatting:
When creating a text field with the size say 800*300 pixels - it corrects the width and it became exact 230 pixels. When I go to another field  - previous seems to be correct sized (800*300). 
When I try to work with this field - it becomes 230 pixels width again.
It drives me crazy I can't work!
If I create a new project - everything works fine.
But I can't do anything with my initial project.
What's the problem? Is there any wy to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the css of the block to match the dimensions you need. Select the text box first and on the Right hand sidebar, you should find a CSS option.

Comment: Just realised this was asked a year ago. I hope you managed to get around it somehow :)

Comment: Thank you. Solved this issue by getting rid of google web designer:)